# How to add collision detection to 2d objects in ursina?

Tags: python, entity, collision-detection

Hi i was wondering how to add collision detection to 2d entitys in ursina. I am a beginner so this is very difficult for me. Here's my code attached:

```
from ursina import *

def update():
    if held_keys['a']:    
        player1.x -= 1 * time.dt
    if held_keys['d']:    
        player1.x += 1 * time.dt
    if held_keys['w']:    
        player1.y += 1 * time.dt
    if held_keys['s']:    
        player1.y -= 1 * time.dt
        
    if held_keys['j']:    
        player2.x -= 1 * time.dt
    if held_keys['l']:    
        player2.x += 1 * time.dt
    if held_keys['i']:    
        player2.y += 1 * time.dt
    if held_keys['k']:    
        player2.y -= 1 * time.dt



root = Ursina()

player_texture1 = load_texture('assets/player1.png')
player_texture2 = load_texture('assets/player2.png')

player1 = Entity(model = 'quad', scale = (1,1), texture = player_texture1)
player2 = Entity(model = 'quad', scale = (1,1), texture = player_texture2)



root.run()
```

Comment: See the official ursina engine tutorial here : https://www.ursinaengine.org/collision.html. Before asking a question here, feel free to check if an answer is available on the official website, it's full of useful tutorials ;) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code: " collider='box' ", e.g. I have a code that goes:

```
class Floor(Entity):
    def __init__(self, position=(0, -103, 0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent=scene,
            position=position,
            model='cube',
            texture = 'white_cube',
            color = color.rgb(34,139,34),
            scale = 200,
            double_sided=True)
```

To add collisions to the entity you can just add it as any other parameter:

```
class Floor(Entity):
    def __init__(self, position=(0, -103, 0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent=scene,
            position=position,
            model='cube',
   ------>  collider='box',  <--------
            texture = 'white_cube',
            color = color.rgb(34,139,34),
            scale = 200,
            double_sided=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, what worked for me was using the method `player1.intersects()`:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.shaders import lit_with_shadows_shader

app = Ursina()

window.title = 'My Game'                # The window title
window.borderless = True               # Show a border
window.fullscreen = False               # Do not go Fullscreen
window.exit_button.visible = False      # Do not show the in-game red X that loses the window
window.fps_counter.enabled = False       # Show the FPS (Frames per second) counter

player1 = Entity(model='cube',color=color.red, scale_y=1,texture="crate", collider='box',shader=lit_with_shadows_shader)
player1.position = (0,0)

player2 = Entity(model='sphere',color=color.blue, scale_y=1,texture="crate", collider='box',shader=lit_with_shadows_shader)
player2.position = (0,2)

def update():   # update gets automatically called.



    player1.x += held_keys['d'] * .1
    player1.x -= held_keys['a'] * .1
    player1.y += held_keys['w'] * .1
    player1.y -= held_keys['s'] * .1
    player2.x += held_keys['l'] * .2
    player2.x -= held_keys['j'] * .2
    player2.y += held_keys['i'] * .2
    player2.y -= held_keys['k'] * .2

    player1.color=color.red
    if(player1.intersects(player2)):
        player1.color=color.yellow


app.run()   # opens a window and starts the game.
```

Answer (score -1):

Ursina has a built in 2d platformer engine that take cares of that.

Comment: This is not a very useful post. At least attempt to relate your statement to the situation of the OP and their code. Or give some context or your own code example that demonstrates your point.